# How to design header with 3 buttons in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to design header like whatsapp chat page where on right hand side we have 3 buttons search,call and carousal ..

Same i want to design in contentPage using xamarin.forms.

I am able to add carousal by using ToolbarItems but how can i add other two button(search and call)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWlgX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the toolbar items to achieve this. Just add additional items.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="ToolbarItems.Views.MainView">
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ToolbarItem Name="Menu1" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
  <ToolbarItem Name="Menu2" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
 </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>    
</ContentPage>
```

If you set the `Order` of the item to `Secondary` your item gets added to a menu like the one on the right hand side (the 3 dots). To achieve your look you would create something like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="ToolbarItems.Views.MainView">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="Search" Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="Call" Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="Additional1" Order="Secondary" Priority="0" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="Additional2" Order="Secondary" Priority="1" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>    
</ContentPage>
```

This will create something pretty close to what you want on Android. On iOS however this looks a bit different. If you want to achieve a similar look you will have to resort to custom renderers.

Comment: Do you have any example of custom renderers