# Xamarin Forms: Unable to click Frame when overlayed over Grid using RelativeLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

This is what I'm trying to acheive. The green blob is a button(Or a stacklayout or a frame).I was able to change the the colors of the selected and unselected tabs. But I'm just not able to implement this. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
I've thrown away the TabbedPage and implemeted tabs using frames and a grid. I'm now using a RelativeLayout to get the button over the Grid. The Xaml is below

```
   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid
            Margin="0"
            Padding="0"
            ColumnSpacing="0"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            IsClippedToBounds="False"
            RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Frame
                x:Name="Explore"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                AutomationId="Explore"
                BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColorExplore}"
                ClassId="Explore"
                OutlineColor="Transparent">
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapTabCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference Explore}" />
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <StackLayout
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Style="{StaticResource NoSpaceStack}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image
                        HeightRequest="29"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Source="exploreiconwhite.png"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        WidthRequest="30" />
                    <customRenderers:ExtendedLabel
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Style="{StaticResource TabbedTitle}"
                        Text="Explore" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame
                x:Name="MyAccount"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                AutomationId="MyAccount"
                BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColorMyAccount}"
                ClassId="MyAccount"
                OutlineColor="Transparent">
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapTabCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference MyAccount}" />
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <StackLayout
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Style="{StaticResource NoSpaceStack}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image
                        HeightRequest="27"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Source="Myaccounticonwhite.png"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        WidthRequest="30" />
                    <customRenderers:ExtendedLabel
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Style="{StaticResource TabbedTitle}"
                        Text="My Account" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
        <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Frame
                BorderRadius="50"
                HeightRequest="67"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                OutlineColor="Transparent"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                  Property=Y,
                                                                  Constant=-140}"
                WidthRequest="67">
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CreatePlanCommand}" />
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image
                        HeightRequest="32"
                        Source="createplaniconwhite.png"
                        WidthRequest="39" />
                    <Label
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource SofiaProSemiBold}"
                        FontSize="10"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Text="Create Plan"
                        TextColor="White" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

But now when I click on part of the frame which is over the tabs, the tab's tapped event fires :(...How do I make the GreenFrames tapped event fire?

Comment: Tabbed page behavior is different on IOS and android, in ios it shows on bottom with image and android its on top wthout mage.... i dnt know how this is possible on xamarin.forms....

Comment: Do you know how I could do this on Xamarin Native?

Comment: you can achieve same thing in xamarin.forms using toolbar items, check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305187/how-to-design-header-with-3-buttons-in-xamarin-forms